# Transfer rows with null values to a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code. The issue is that this is running on a sheet that has over 4,000 rows and takes a while to finish. Looking for a faster way to do this.

```
'Transfer rows with null Updated_SAT into SAT_errors sheet

Sheet4.Range("A1:BN1").Copy Sheet8.Range("A1")

Dim j As Integer
j = 2
For i = 2 To max_row
    If (Len(Sheet4.Range("BN" & i).Value) = 0 Or Sheet4.Range("BN" & i).Value = 0) Then
    Sheet4.Rows(i).Copy Sheet8.Range("A" & j)
    j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
Dim k As Integer
k = 2
For i = 2 To max_row
    If (IsEmpty(Sheet4.Range("BN" & i).Value) Or Sheet4.Range("BN" & i).Value = 0) Then
    Sheet4.Range("A" & i & ":" & "BN" & i).Delete
    i = i - 1
    End If
    k = k + 1
    If k = max_row Then
    Exit For
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: Explain what you are trying to do. If  `Sheet 4` cell `BN` is empty, copy to `Sheet 8`. What is your second loop trying to do? Loop back through the same range and delete those same rows?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for. The reason the code is slow is because you trying to copy, paste, & delete inside your loop which means **every loop** incurs 3 instances of action. This method has the action taken outside of the loop which means you only have 3 instances of action.

Even better would be to simply filter your column by blanks and then copy/paste/delete the cells shown by filter. But you took the loop approach, so this would be a better way to complete the ask with a loop.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Blanks()

Dim ws4 As Worksheet: Set ws4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")
Dim ws8 As Worksheet: Set ws8 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet8")

Dim LRow As Long, MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range, MyUnion As Range

LRow = ws4.Range("BN" & ws4.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set MyRange = ws4.Range("BN2:BN" & LRow)

For Each MyCell In MyRange
    If MyCell = "" Then
        If Not MyUnion Is Nothing Then
            Set MyUnion = Union(MyUnion, MyCell)
        Else
            Set MyUnion = MyCell
        End If
    End If
Next MyCell

If Not MyUnion Is Nothing Then
    MyUnion.EntireRow.Copy
    ws8.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    MyUnion.EntireRow.Delete
End If

End Sub
```